How do you collect your invoices for accounting?
I have a bunch of invoices from the services I use to do my work.
My inbox is a chaotic mess of billing emails from various services. Manually sorting through them to find invoices is a nightmare. Each month, I download the CSVs of bank transactions and manually go through each to match the relevant invoices, then I hand them over to my accountant.
There are services like Dext or Bill, but they don't work properly in Europe. I can't even sign up with my phone number.
Does anyone else feel overwhelmed by this? Have you discovered a better way to automatically collect and organize billing emails? Do you use any tools?
I would especially like to hear from you if your HQ is based in Europe.

Can't you simply export the invoices into files organized into folders for each service?

If you aren't willing to pay someone to do it, then you'll need an app to do so. I self-host my invoicing program - it generates the invoice based on the work I type into it, I hit the "Email" button to send it off.
When a payment comes in, I go into the program, apply the payment, and hit "Email" again. The client and I have a copy of the invoices, and it's searchable by Invoice Number in my email app (Gmail).
Why complicate it? Yes, it took a few hours for me to set it up, but it's only a couple minutes to do the billing now.

@CanadiaLuke For what kinda services do you generate those invoices?

@JorgeLuiz Everything - my entire Freelance portfolio goes through there if there is any expectation of money changing hands. I can access it from my phone if I get called to a client's office for work, or from my computer.
